# Solr spellcheck not working despite configuration

Tags: java, solr, configuration, spell-checking

I've looked at other posts but can't seem to sort my issue out. I have spellcheck turned on, but it isn't returning any suggestions. The spellcheck object is in the result, but it's always empty. I'm currently spellchecking using a field called `name`:

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

And I've turned on spellcheck in my `/select` handler with the following settings:

```
<str name="spellcheck">on</str>
<str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
<str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">0</str>
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>
```

And I have the following spellcheck search component:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="field">name</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
    <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
    <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
    <float name="maxQueryFrequency">1</float>
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">1</float>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

I have a document with the field value of `"name":"Sample document"`. When I try things like `sampel` I get 0 results and nothing suggested in the spellcheck. Same thing with other words.

I've been over all the settings and they seem fine (as far as I can tell from their description in the docs), I can't figure out why it's not suggesting terms that are in the field. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

For reference, here's the text field type I'm not using for the spellcheck field:

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: You can't use a string field in that case, since `sampel` will be compared to the whole string - `Sample document`. That difference is far too large to be considered a correction. Instead use a field type base on text, such as `text_en`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Good point. I changed it so that there's a separate spellcheck field which is a text one, then added a copy field from name into spellcheck. However, it's still not working (I updated conf, reloaded core, reindexed and everything).

Comment: @MatsLindh for reference, I've added the text field type I'm using for spellcheck into the question

Comment: (I also updated search component to look at spellcheck field.)